# react-image-gallery automatically returns to a previous photo while setting new details

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, gallery

I have a gallery on my page made like below. When you press the button to change photo it works and set a new description but then it immediately returns to the previous photo. It is caused by `onSlide={setImageDeteails}` I have been struggling with it for a while and I can not find a way to fix it. Do you have any idea? 
Thank you for your help in advance.

```
    const StyledImageDetails = styled.div`
      padding: 1em 2em;

      .title {
        font-weight: 700;
        color: ${(props) => props.theme.mainColor};
      }

      .desc {
        display: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 1000px) {
        padding-left: 2em;
        .desc {
          display: block;
        }
      }
    `;
    const AsideGallery = ({
  active,
  images,
  closeModal,
  openModal,
  title,
  icon,
  currentImage,
  setImageDetails
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledAsideGallery>
        <CustomIconHeading icon={icon} text={title} />
        <StyledGalleryWrapper
          onClick={openModal}
          bgd={images.length && images[0].original}
        >
          <StyledPreviewWrapper>{showImages(images)}</StyledPreviewWrapper>
          <StyledImageTitle>
            {images.length && images[0].originalTitle} <ArrowIcon />
          </StyledImageTitle>
        </StyledGalleryWrapper>
      </StyledAsideGallery>

      <ReactModal
        isOpen={active}
        onRequestClose={closeModal}
        shouldCloseOnEsc={true}
        shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}
        overlayClassName="ReactModal__Overlay-custom"
        className="ReactModal__Content-custom"
      >
        <ModalHeader closeModal={closeModal} icon={icon} text={title} />
        <StyledModalWrapper>
          <StyledRow>
            <StyledColumn width="70">
              <ImageGallery
                items={images}
                lazyLoad={true}
                slideDuration={750}
                showPlayButton={false}
                showBullets={false}
                showFullscreenButton={false}
                showThumbnails={true}
                renderRightNav={renderRightNav}
                renderLeftNav={renderLeftNav}
                onSlide={setImageDetails}
              />  
            </StyledColumn>
            <StyledColumn width="30">
              <StyledImageDetails>
                <p className="title">{images[currentImage] && images[currentImage].originalTitle}</p>
                <p className="desc">{images[currentImage] && images[currentImage].description}</p>  
              </StyledImageDetails>
            </StyledColumn>
          </StyledRow>
        </StyledModalWrapper>
      </ReactModal>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it.. 
It was a bug in my version of react-image-gallery.. I have updated it and it works properly.